# How to show total reward points on checkout page in Opencart 3.0

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module, opencart-events

I using Opencart 3.0, I just want to show the total sum of reward points (I have renamed as BV Points) of the complete order on the checkout page as shown in the attached image. I don't want to purchase any paid plugin for it. Only I just want to show the total points at the bottom on the checkout page rest all are useless for me.  Please help me

[image]

[image]

Comment: as per quantity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that ..

In file:
`catalog/view/theme/{THEME_DIRECTORY}/template/checkout/cart.twig`

Replace:

```
{% for product in products %}
```

By:

```
{% set points = 0 %}
{% for product in products %}
{% if product.reward %}
{% set points = points + product.reward|replace({'BV Points: ':''})  %}
{% endif %}
```

---

And then add:

```
<tr>
  <td><strong>Total points:</strong></td>
  <td class="text-left" dir="ltr">{{ points }}</td>
</tr>
```

before:

```
{% for total in totals %}
```